# Reduce For loop in Map

Tags: java, dictionary

This is my code:

```
package vvv;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class test {

public static void main(String args[]){
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    map.put(1, "demo");
    map.put(20, "fdemo");
    map.put(60, "gdemo");
    map.put(500, "udemo");
    map.put(8000, "odemo");
    // etc
    int b = 7999;
    for(int i =1; i<=8000; i++)
    {
        if(i == b)
            System.out.println(map.get(b));
    }

}

}
```

I don't want to use a big "for loop" just to find a result from map, and in addition, I can't change a key in the map (for example I can't change 500 to 4).

What should I do to reduce my loop condition?

Comment: This code is non sense, what's the purpose of your loop?

Comment: It's just an example

Comment: An example for what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would iterate over all the keys in the Map :

```
for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
    ...
}
```

However, I don't see the point in your loop, since you only do something for a specific key (7999), so your loop can be reduced to:

```
System.out.println(map.get(b));
```

Changing a key is not something you can do with a single method. You have to first remove the old key, and then insert the new key, using the same value.

```
if (map.containsKey(500))
    map.put(4,map.remove(500));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Integer key = entry.getKey();
    if(b==key);
        println entry.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
for (Integer theKey : map.keySet()) {
    String val=map.get(thekey);
    ....
}
```

If your are just trying to check if some key exists or not ,you don't even need the loops, use `map.containKey(some_key)`

And you may need to pay attention that if your key is your customer class rather than primitive type, you need to override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` method, or , something bad will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it will work fine. No need to iterate map you just use map.conytainsKey(key) method.

```
{
  String tempString=null;
  tempString=((map.containsKey(b)?map.get(b):" "));
  System.out.println(tempString);
}
```

or you may also write like this

```
{

  System.out.println((map.containsKey(b)?map.get(b):" "));
}
```